# What does ^ operator do?

Tags: c#, math

I thought that ^ did that.
I expected:

```
10^0=1
10^1=10
10^2=100
```

What I'm getting

```
10^0=10
10^1=11
10^2=8
```

the actual code is

```
int value = 10 ^ exp;
```

replacing exp for 0, 1, and 2
What does the ^ operator do?

Comment: ^ does not mean "power" in C#. It seems to be an xor opn

Comment: ^ is the XOR, not "Power Of": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx - there is no "Power Of" Operator, but a library function: Math.Pow: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx

Comment: Why do people continue to post the same answer, even when the answer was posted almost 5 minutes ago?

Comment: @George Some people may not have seen the new answers yet if the page was opened before said answers were posted. StackOverflow informs you of this with "n New Answers Posted" notifications, but they may not have seen this.

Comment: -1. Why don't people look up the operator in the docs? Or search for duplicates...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Math.Pow(x, y) to get x raised to the power of y. You were doing an XOR. [C# operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You want to do:

```
Math.Pow(10, exp);
```

This actually produces a `double` though so you'll need to cast it down if you really want an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

In c#, ^ is the [logical XOR operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: It is also the __bitwise XOR__ and that is used by the OP

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you need you use `Math.pow(x, y)` to do `x^y` in C#. The ^ operator is actually a logical XOR operator on the bits of the two numbers. More information on the logical XOR can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no operator for this.  Use [`Math.Pow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx).

There is a full list of all the [C# operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) with linked documentation on each one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.Power(10,exp) works like charm...
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, the ^ operator is the logical XOR operator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`^` is the XOR operator.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor

If you want to raise a number to a power, use

```
Math.Pow(num, exp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `^` is equivalent for `XOR`, that's why 10 ^ 0 = 10 because

```
1010 XOR    1010 XOR
0000 =      0010 =
1010        1000
```

You need to use [Math.Pow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx) method.

P.S. = 10^2 actually returns 8...